# Is a subset of a null set always a null set?

Tags: measure-theory

I cannot find counterexample to a definition which I think is overcomplicated. 
 **I have a definition of null set:**

- $(S, \Sigma, \mu) - \text{measure space},$
- $E \in \Sigma, \mu(E) = 0.$
- If $N$ is a subset of $E$, then I think also $\mu(N) = 0$.

But the definition says that this holds only if $N \in \Sigma$.

Why it is so? May I find counterexample to it?

Comment: Positive measures are monotonic, so measurable subsets of a set of measure $0$ will also have measure $0$. Non measurable subsets can behave quite badly. See, for example, Vitality's example of a non Lebesgue measurable set in the real line.

Comment: The problem is that N might not be measurable. You might want to look up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The measure is only defined on the $\sigma-$algebra $\sum,$ so it could have no sense to talk about $\mu(N)$ in the case where $N\notin\sum$ ; it is why the definition add this point.

For example in the $\sigma-$ algebra $\sum=\{\varnothing,S\}$ with $\mu(\varnothing)=\mu(S)=0,$ then all non-empty proper subsets $E$ of $S$ verify $E\subset S$  but $E\not\in\sum.$

Note that if $N\subset E$ and $\mu(E)=0$ then we say that $N$ is a negligible set, and that we can always extend the mesure $\mu$ in a mesure $\mu^*$ (completed of $\mu$) such that all negligible sets are measurable.

Comment: Could you please extend the answer at this point: "it could have no sense to talk about $\mu(N)$. And one more question, is it possible that I find such $N$ that $N \subset  E$, but $N \notin \Sigma$ ?

Comment: I will edit that !